# ndimage.label() giving "data type not supported" error

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy, runtime-error

I'm trying to do some very simple segmentation with python and using scipy. What I try to do here is to label and image (a numpy ndarray) and then calculate the size of some of the patches, remove the largest of them and then label it again.

However the last `ndimage.label( fin )` gives me an error

```
RunTimeError: data type not supported
```

Any idea what could be causing the error? Array a and array fin are both the same datatype that's int32. Also the label function should default the structure element and output to the same types as they are not defined. This is really bugging me.

Here's the little test code I'm running:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

def main():

    a = np.array([  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]  ])

    labeled_array, numpatches = ndimage.label(a)

    sizes = ndimage.sum(a,labeled_array,range(1,numpatches+1))

    mp = np.where(sizes == sizes.max())[0]+1 

    max_index = np.zeros(numpatches + 1, np.uint8)
    max_index[mp] = 1
    max_feature = max_index[labeled_array]

    fin = max_feature^a

    lArr, npa = ndimage.label( fin )

    return

main()
```

Comment: your code works OK for me in scipy versions 0.11.0 and 0.14.0.dev-86f95bd. also, `fin` and `a` will be `np.int64` by default, but it still works fine if I cast them to `np.int32`.

Comment: Just checked my scipy version and it seems to be 0.12.0. I installed it bundled with Anaconda. Weird that it's broken in the later version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this idea from ali_m's comment. I thought of trying to force cast the array types to `np.int64` and that seemed to fix the problem. Not sure though why the arrays were np.int32 by default in the first place.

```
a = np.array([  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]  ], np.int64)
```

Anyway casting the type to np.int64 seemed to fix the problem.